# Are Lambdas the most efficient way to perform transformations on dataframes in python?

Tags: python, lambda, jupyter-notebook

today I started working with a large dataframe in python and tried to replace a column with a scalar multiple of itself.

For example:

```
df['some_column'] = [1,2,3,4,5] * 10 = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

I tried a two different ways to accomplish this:

First way:

```
df['some_column'] = df['some_column']*10
```

Second way:

```
df['some_column'] = df['some_column'].apply(lambda x: x*10)
```

I used the timeit function and noticed they both had similar runtimes. With the first way, the Jupyter Notebook kernel crashed when I included the entire dataset, so I assumed it ran out of memory. The second way worked as intended, so I'm guessing its less memory intensive.

**Question:** Am I correct in assuming lambda functions use less memory? If so, is it best practice to use Lambdas as frequently as possible? Are there any comparable ways that might be less resource-intensive than the two I listed here?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I tried this in a different environment and it didn't crash so my earlier assumption on memory is not correct. In the set I am working with, the data type of 'some_column' is int64. The runtimes of the two ways were 35ms and 56ms, respectively.

Comment: First hunch would be: no; lambdas will always be slower. Did you check these two are doing the same?

Comment: @sacha question is not about speed, though

Comment: What is the `dtype` of `some_column`?

Comment: You need to check if your crash is reproducible. 40k rows is not that big and you shouldn't be running out of memory either way. The entire premise is that your crash is due to running out of memory but you don't actually know that.

Comment: If you really get similar runtimes it's likely an `object`-column. Simple suggestion: Avoid them at whatever cost. You can probably optimize memory and speed by using a not-object column.

Comment: The data type for 'some_column' is int64. I realized though I was timing them with a read_csv() in the mix, so the times I provided earlier are not accurate. The first way ran in 35ms, the second way in 56 ms.

Thanks pvg, that's a good point. I'm working on an online notebook right now and I'm having a bit of trouble finding the logfile or some other way to check specifics on why it crashed. I'll see if I can replicate it in another environment.

Comment: I checked it out on my desktop and it didn't crash, so my assumption above is incorrect! Must have been some other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrong for both time and memory consumption. And you're wrong about your question: It is not about `lambda` alone, but about `apply` and `lambda`.

Using profiling shows how far this approach is less efficient than parallel functions implemented in `pandas`.

#### `apply` and Lambdas are slower

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s = pd.Series(range(10000000))

In [3]: %timeit s * 10
100 loops, best of 3: 13.7 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit s.multiply(10)                     # Using the function itself gives
100 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop             # same thing as above

In [5]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: x * 10)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.92 s per loop                 # Factor 200 for timing
```

#### `apply` and Lambdas use more memory

```
In [1]: %load_ext memory_profiler

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: s = pd.Series(range(10000000))

In [4]: %memit s * 10
peak memory: 163.02 MiB, increment: 38.15 MiB

In [5]: %memit s.multiply(10)                      # Using the function itself gives
peak memory: 163.01 MiB, increment: 37.96 MiB      # same thing as above

In [6]: %memit s.apply(lambda x: x * 10)
peak memory: 1202.03 MiB, increment: 1077.40 MiB   # Factor 7 for memory
```

Lambdas and `apply` are useful in some cases, but they should not be overused.

Could you try some profiling on your operations? Maybe using a subset of your dataframe to avoid the crash. I would be surprised this is a memory issue occurring with `multiply` and not with `apply`.

Bonus: A bit of reading about [pandas performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html) that you may find interesting.

Comment: 'My measurement is different than your measurement' is not really an answer or explanation. You have to explain why your measurement is right and what is wrong with the measurement presented in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to python so I appreciate the link. I think this answers my first question: "Am I correct in assuming lambdas use less memory?": Answer = no. Since that's 'no', I guess I would want to use option 1 more frequently, if possible.

Comment: @pvg that's part of my point : OP stated an hypothesis without providing measurements so I show how to do so and suggest to replicate. And, I provide a document with clues of why parallelized implementations are more efficient than apply and pure python. We will discuss OP's measurements if he provides some and ask for input about it.

Comment: @FabienP no, the OP also has times. They just don't match yours. You just declared them 'wrong'. They might be wrong, but you don't really know, just like the OP. In fact, even with the later edits, it's not really clear why your numbers and the poster's numbers are so different.

Comment: @pvg, OP added timing in comments, and obviously on a  very small test set. Whereas I used a 10 000 000 rows series to better reflect the behavior OP can observes on his "large" (40 000 rows) dataset. It is not meant to be compared directly, there is no point in that as it will vary depending on the system performances, but rather to emphasize my point.Last, I do not state that OP's **numbers** are wrong (although `apply`'s slow speed is common knowledge), but that his **intuition / hypothesis** "assuming lambda functions use less memory" is wrong.

Comment: the timings were there from the beginning and have been moved around several times. they are not 'in the comments'. This is a pretty silly argument but my points are pretty clear, and your answer doesn't address them at all. in fact _you still have no idea why the posters numbers are what they are_. if you're going to be stridently certain about answering something, you should try to find out what it is you are actually answering.